# MPI_COMM_SPLIT does not give a new reduced size

Tags: fortran, mpi

I use MPI to parallellize my Fortran code. `MPI_Comm_reduce()` is used to sum up the results from the different ranks. In some cases only a minor part of the available ranks are necessary for the computations and I therefore want to construct a communicator containing only the size1 necessary ranks,e.g. ranks 0,1,2,...,size1-1

```
IF(rank.LE.size1-1)THEN; color=1; ELSE; color=2; ENDIF
key=0
CALL MPI_COMM_SPLIT(MPI_COMM_WORLD,1,key,REDCOMM,ierr) 
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(REDCOMM,sizered,ierr)
```

However, with `size=8` and `size1=6` the last call returns `sizered=8` instead of 6!
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

At first, you should try to build a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that evidences the issue.

From `MPI_Comm_split()` man page

> **Synopsis**
>
> int MPI_Comm_split(MPI_Comm comm, int color, int key, MPI_Comm
>   *newcomm)
>
> **Input Parameters**
>
> - comm communicator (handle)
> - color control of subset assignment (nonnegative integer). Processes with the same color are in the same new communicator
> - key control of rank assignment (integer)

so this is how you should invoke `MPI_Comm_split()`

```
MPI_COMM_SPLIT(MPI_COMM_WORLD,color,rank,REDCOMM,ierr)
```

use `color` instead of hard coded `1`, otherwise all MPI tasks end up in the same communicator. since you do not need to re-order ranks within the new communicator, you can also use `rank` as the key.

**EDIT**

Since you only care of the first ranks, you can use `MPI_UNDEFINED` as a color for the highest rank. in this case, the highest rank will be in `MPI_COMM_NULL`.

Note you **cannot** invoke `MPI_Comm_size()` on `MPI_COMM_NULL`.

The code would become

```
IF(rank.LT.size1)THEN; color=0; ELSE; color=MPI_UNDEFINED; ENDIF
key=rank
CALL MPI_COMM_SPLIT(MPI_COMM_WORLD,color,key,REDCOMM,ierr) 
IF(rank.LT.size1) CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(REDCOMM,sizered,ierr)
```

Comment: By setting color=1 or 2 you divide mpi_comm_world into two groups, but can only name one group (in my case redcomm). What decides which one of the two groups gets the redcomm name?

Comment: there will be two `REDCOMM` communicators ! one for tasks 0-5 and one for tasks 6-7. keep in mind that from a given MPI task point of view, there is only one `REDCOMM`. if you want only one `REDCOMM` communicator, then you can pass `color=MPI_UNDEFINED`, and in this case, one `REDCOMM` will be `MPI_COMM_NULL`.

Comment: @Sanders you can create a single group with a reduced amount of processes by creating the communicator with a group definition ([`MPI_Comm_create`](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Comm_create.html)).

Comment: @JorgeBellón A simpler way to produce a single group with a subset of processes is simply to set the colour in MPI_Comm_split to MPI_UNDEFINED for those processes that do not need to be part of the resulting communicator(s)

Comment: @IanBush True. It has been a while since I worked with derived communicators. It was not `MPI_Comm_create` but rather `MPI_Comm_create_group` the function I wanted to talk about. The difference is important, as both `MPI_Comm_create` and `MPI_Comm_split` are collectives that involve all the processes in a communicator (for a large amount of processes this becomes noticeable), whereas `MPI_Comm_create_group` only involves the processes that are actually going to belong to the new communicator.

Comment: @JorgeBellón i edited the answer per your valuable comment, thanks !

Comment: I want to use MPI_comm_create to create a new communicator redcomm  by call MPI_comm_create (MPI_comm_world,redgroup,redcomm,ierr). How do I define a group named redgroup containing the ranks 0,1,...,size1-1?

Comment: Please open a new question, it will make things easier for search engines and to keep the titke consistent with the question

Comment: @gilles Do you want questioners to put in the final modified code?